# HorizontalscrollView is stuck when scrolled, with multiple edittexts inside

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, android-softkeyboard, horizontalscrollview

I have an HorizontalScrollView with a linearlayout inside, and I am adding multiple edittexts inside the linearlayout. I added focusableInTouchMode= true and and android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants";

But I can still see some lagging and stuck when I am scrolling the horizontalScrollView. It stucks at some point for half second and then moves.
I am thinking the removing of focus is taking some time. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong.

my horizontalScrollView

```
      <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollIndicators="bottom|top">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid_question_row_holder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/grid_add_row_rel_holder"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/sizeOfEight"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Can someOne suggest where I am going wrong.

Also one more problem I noticed is, some of the edittexts are number based and some edittexts are alphhabets based. When I am touching either based editexts, It takes a second to gain focus.

Any idea on what is happening..?

Comment: How many EditTexts are in the Layout? 2? 10? 10000?

Comment: @Kelevandos edittexts are in a grid manner. 5 to 10 edittexts per row, which are 20 to 30 rows. ie. some 100 edittexts or more...

Comment: So 100-300, this is much and will most probably lag because of View lifecycle methods. you should use a RecyclerView for that, recycling the EditTexts so that only the visible ones are actually in memory :-)